# GCC4 - ARMv5 register allocations

Tags: assembly, arm, gcc4

Is there a way to ask GCC to generate code that uses the registers in a way unlike the standard ABI for that architecture.

I am using an ARMv4 chip (LPC2000) and I need my fast interrupts to be faster.

I have a FIQ routine, but I have to store r0..r7 on the stack, this seems pointless as FIQ mode as it's own bank of registers R8..r15.  I want to use those instead and save 16 instruction cycles used to push and pop stuff off the stack.

Before anybody states the obvious: re-write the FIQ handler in assembly language, yes I know I can do that, This question is more specific.

Is there a #pragma or __attribute__ or switch that  tells GCC4 to change the order it allocates registers within a function?

Comment: If you are interested in that much performance you should just use asm, or compile the C code then modify/tune the result by hand.  Otherwise you are probably not going to gain much for anything but a trivial isr (which would be simple to implement in asm).

Comment: Note from what I read the lpc2000 is ARM7TDMI based which is ARMv4 not ARMv5

Comment: @dwelch: typo corrected. does not change the question through and it will still affect v5.

Comment: The produced assembly is already pretty effecient, the largest part is now the pointless push and pop. Inline assembly makes it larger as it also uses r2,r3 etc.  I could write as a .S module, but was hoping GCC would be a little more clever.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A. This *should* be correctly optimized away when you declare the function with the `interrupt` pragma:

```
void f () __attribute__ ((interrupt ("FIQ")));
```

Source: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes

B. **But** I find an open bug report that this currently *does not* optimize away the push/pop of the relevant registers. The bug report has been classified as a 'missed optimization' and has been open since being confirmed in June 2011.

Source: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48429

Comment: Yes I know about interrupt "FIQ" but it does not generate the code I want. I did not realise I've found a bug. Is there a workround?

Comment: @JasonMorgan - I do not know if there is a workaround. From the bug report, what I gather is that using `r8` onwards in the function is 'expected behavior' when one uses this attribute. I would probably just use it, and wait for a fix. Or, consider helping them with a patch.